# php storing ip address in mysql database

Tags: mysql, networking, ip-address

this is more a question about design application.
I was wondering if anyone might explain to me how could i store in a database ip addresses dns they belong and other info's about the computer like if it's a network node or wi fi etc basically was thinking on structuring based on network type and if i have more than one ip class like 88.* and 89.* should i store in different tables.. or have more then one networkname / area.
i hope someone understands my question or at least get's a sense of it because neither i don't know how to explain exactly what i need. i apologize

Comment: What's the goal? For a network you manage? Otherwise you might not be able to get all of that information (how would to tell if something is wifi?)  And you shouldn't need more tables for different subnets...

Comment: umm no, it's not for network manangement or anything like that i only need to store some ip lists with some fake generated data about them and run some update / inserts querys on this tables / table, and i`m looking for a way to structure it for further improving without rebuild everything from scratch. the entire project i think would be defined best by the word simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function which make optimize form for ip address for storing in b.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton